# Zoom a node in and out using D3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am drawing a node (circle) and trying to zoom it in and out using D3 Javascript. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sample2</title>
<style>

.node {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
stroke: #999;
stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 1000;//960,
height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-120)
.linkDistance(30)
.size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

//Draw the Circle
var circle = svg.append("circle");

force 
.nodes(d3.values(circle))
.start();

var resourceNode = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(circle)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(2); })
    .attr("r", 10)
    .call(force.drag);

resourceNode.append("circle");

function mouseover() {
     d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("r", 20);
     }

    function mouseout() {
     d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("r", 10);
     }

    force.on("tick", function() {
     resourceNode.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

     resourceNode.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
   });

   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

In the code above, you may notice that I added the two functions: `mouseover` and `mouseout`. These two functions are for zooming in and out the node. I could manage to zoom the node in and out as soon as I moved the mouse over the node. My problem is: the node freezes in one position at the top left of the canvas and do not move anymore. If I delete the codes that are related to the zooming functions, I will be able to move the node anywhere I want. Could anyone please help me solve this problem? The zooming functions are OK but the node does not move anymore. It will move when I delete the zooming functions. I do not know what the problem is. Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do there. Something like [this](http://vida.io/documents/3CW34j4cXRW94rmHj)?

Comment: This is what I want to do.

Comment: Ok, I'll add this as an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're only controlling the positions of the `g` elements through the force layout, not of the circle. You shouldn't really pass SVG elements as data to force layout or to D3 in general -- it will work technically, but almost certainly won't do what you want.

I've modified your example to do what you want [here](http://vida.io/documents/3CW34j4cXRW94rmHj). Note that I've added actual data to pass to force layout and `.data()` and draw elements according to that. The `circle` elements are now attached to the `g` elements as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I followed the link you added. It is working in there perfectly. I copied and pasted the script part of your modification. Unfortunately, I could not even see the node. Any idea why that is happening, please?

Comment: Just call `drawD3document({});` at the end.

Comment: I have added it at the end of the script (before closing the script tag). It is not working yet. drawD3Document({});

Comment: You also may have to change `d3.select("#canvas")` to `d3.select("body")`.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. It is working now. I could not even notice the canvas word in the code. One more question, please. In your modification, you send data instead of SVG elements. Is that correct? What does "g" do in the code? Any idea, please?

Comment: Yes, as I've said in my answer, you wouldn't normally use SVG elements where you've used them. `g` is a grouping element -- technically, you don't need that, but it was in your code so I kept it.

Comment: How would the code look if I want to delete the "g" element? I simply deleted it but the node itself disappeared too.

Comment: You would need to adjust the way the coordinates are set, too. Leave the `g`s for now -- there's no real disadvantage to having them.